# Insert entity with foreign keys with hibernate and vraptor via POST

Tags: java, jquery, json, hibernate, vraptor

Im trying to insert a json taxistaPonto in database using Ajax with JQuery via POST, with other entity without foreign key was fine, but i don't know how to insert this entity with foreign keys. Im sending the requests in Json format. Maybe my json isnt in right format? How can i insert this entity in my database?

Model:

```
@Entity(name="taxistaPonto")
public class TaxistaPonto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_taxista",nullable=false)
    private Taxista taxista;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_ponto",nullable=false)
    private Ponto ponto;

    public TaxistaPonto() {
        super();
    }

    public TaxistaPonto(Integer id, Taxista taxista, Ponto ponto) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.taxista = taxista;
        this.ponto = ponto;
    }//... getters and setters
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@Path("/taxistaponto")
public class TaxistaPontoController { 

    @Inject
    private Result result;
    @Inject
    private TaxistaPontoDAO taxistaPontoDAO;

    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Post("/add")
    public void add(TaxistaPonto taxistaPonto){
        taxistaPontoDAO.salvar(taxistaPonto);
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
public void salvar(TaxistaPonto taxistaPonto) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        try {
            session.persist(taxistaPonto);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

        HibernateUtil.shutdown(session);
    }
```

Here is my request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var carro =
    {"descricao" : "carro mt legal", "placa" : "12938713"};

    var taxista =
    {id : 5, "nome" : "12:58", "sexo" : "trans", "login" : "loginmeu", "senha" : "minhasenhsa", carro : carro};;

    var ponto =
    {id : 8,"latitude" : "40", "longitude" : "96"};

    var taxistaPonto =
    {taxista : taxista, ponto : ponto};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://expotaxi.herokuapp.com/taxistaponto/add",
        data: JSON.stringify(taxistaPonto),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("sucesso");
        },
        error : function(data){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

@EDIT:This is the excpetion: 
[image]

and is shown a error like this too "uncaught exception: out of memory"

Comment: whats the exception saying?

Comment: "uncaught exception: out of memory"

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the taxistaPonto Object on Salver method. Can you share the parsing logic/handling request on server end.

For your case, you can rectify this error on server end while processing the add request.

Comment: How can i do this? I've tried many ways but i cant figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Seems your "add" API service was not reachable or not active on the link (https://expotaxi.herokuapp.com/taxistaponto/add). So that your are getting 404 error.                                                                            Solutions: Makes sure your server side is API(method) was reachable from browser or deployed on server and active. Then try again.